# javafx custom ui component FadeTransition doesn't working correctly

Tags: java, javafx

## Fade transition doesn't working correctly

I created new javafx ui component and added FadeTransition, but unfortunately fade transition doesn't working.
When I was entered JFXButton background color changed but fade transition doesn't working.
How can I fixed it ?

#### Here my code

#### Launcher class

```
public class Main extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    AnimationButton animationButton = new AnimationButton();
    Scene scene = new Scene(animationButton);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("btn.css").toExternalForm());
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Custom Control");
    primaryStage.setWidth(300);
    primaryStage.setHeight(200);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

#### AnimationButton.java

```
public class AnimationButton extends AnchorPane{

    private Duration fadeDuration = Duration.millis(1000);
    private FadeTransition fadeTransition;

    @FXML
    private JFXButton animationButton;

    public AnimationButton() {
        
              
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("AnimationButton.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(new AnchorPane());
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    
        animationButton.getStyleClass().add("animation-button");
        fadeDuration = new Duration(3000);
        fadeTransition = new FadeTransition(fadeDuration, animationButton);
        fadeTransition.setAutoReverse(true);
        fadeTransition.setFromValue(0);
        fadeTransition.setToValue(1);
        
    }

    @FXML
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
        fadeTransition.setCycleCount(1); // this way autoreverse wouldn't kick
        fadeTransition.playFromStart();
    }

    @FXML
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {

        fadeTransition.setCycleCount(2); // starting from autoreverse
        fadeTransition.playFrom(fadeDuration);
    }
    ...
}
```

#### Here my fxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<fx:root type="AnchorPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.112" 
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <JFXButton text="Enjoy it!" id="animationButton" onMouseEntered="#mouseEntered" onMouseExited="#mouseExited"/>
    </children>
</fx:root>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't completely clear what about your current code isn't working, but I'm assuming the following:

1. You want your button to fade in when the mouse enters and fade out when the mouse exits.
2. The fade functionality isn't working quite the way you want.

   - Trying something similar to your setup I noticed the node won't fade out if the mouse exits before the animation has finished.

---

### Problem

In what appears to be an attempt to reverse the animation you are modifying the [`cycleCount`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Animation.html#cycleCountProperty) property. That property does not affect the direction of play but rather how many cycles the animation plays before stopping:

> Defines the number of cycles in this animation. The `cycleCount` may be `INDEFINITE` for animations that repeat indefinitely, but must otherwise be `> 0`.
>
> It is not possible to change the `cycleCount` of a running `Animation`. If the value of `cycleCount` is changed for a running `Animation`, the animation has to be stopped and started again to pick up the new value.

You combine setting `cycleCount` with seting [`autoReverse`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Animation.html#autoReverseProperty) to `true` in the hopes that will reverse the animation when you set `cycleCount` to `2`. The `autoReverse` property:

> Defines whether this `Animation` reverses direction on alternating cycles. If `true`, the `Animation` will proceed forward on the first cycle, then reverses on the second cycle, and so on. Otherwise, animation will loop such that each cycle proceeds forward from the start. It is not possible to change the `autoReverse` flag of a running `Animation`. If the value of `autoReverse` is changed for a running `Animation`, the animation has to be stopped and started again to pick up the new value.

This setup may be working somewhat, especially with the use of `playFromStart()` and `playFrom(fadeDuration)`, but is not the correct way to do what you want.

---

### Solution

What you want is to modify the [`rate`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Animation.html#rateProperty) property based on whether the mouse has entered or exited. The `rate` property:

> Defines the direction/speed at which the `Animation` is expected to be played.
>
> The absolute value of `rate` indicates the speed at which the `Animation` is to be played, while the sign of `rate` indicates the direction. A positive value of `rate` indicates forward play, a negative value indicates backward play and `0.0` to stop a running `Animation`.
>
> Rate `1.0` is normal play, `2.0 is`2`time normal,`-1.0` is backwards, etc.
>
> Inverting the `rate` of a running `Animation` will cause the `Animation` to reverse direction in place and play back over the portion of the `Animation` that has already elapsed.

Here's a small example. It uses `Button` instead of `JFXButton` because I didn't feel like pulling in the dependency. Also, it uses the `hover` property but is functionally equivalent to using mouse-entered/mouse-exited handlers.

```
import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button button = new Button("Click me!");
        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            event.consume();
            System.out.println("Button clicked!");
        });

        installAnimation(button);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(button), 300.0, 150.0));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Animation Example");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void installAnimation(Button button) {
        FadeTransition transition = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(250.0), button);
        transition.setFromValue(0.2);
        transition.setToValue(1.0);

        button.hoverProperty().addListener((obs, wasHover, isHover) -> {
            transition.setRate(isHover ? 1.0 : -1.0);
            transition.play();
        });
        button.setOpacity(transition.getFromValue());
    }

}
```

Notice the following:

- The `rate` is set to `1.0` when the mouse *is* hovering (entered) and `-1.0` when the mouse *is not* hovering (exited).
- The `autoReverse` flag remains `false`.
- The `cycleCount` is kept at `1`.
- I call `play()`, not `playFromStart()` or `playFrom(Duration)`. This is important because [`play`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Animation.html#play()):

  > Plays `Animation` from current position in the direction indicated by `rate`. If the `Animation` is running, it has no effect.
  >
  > When rate `> 0` (forward play), if an `Animation` is already positioned at the end, the first cycle will not be played, it is considered to have already finished. This also applies to a backward (`rate < 0`) cycle if an `Animation` is positioned at the beginning. However, if the `Animation` has `cycleCount > 1`, following cycle(s) will be played as usual.
  >
  > When the `Animation` reaches the end, the `Animation` is stopped and the play head remains at the end.

Comment: Thanks a lot for attending, you are right I can use rate and it's working. But I change fx:root from AnchorPane to JFXButton and change some fields from AnimationButton.java files. Now my code correctly working. So thanks for your reputation. Your answer really comfortable for me.